# Why doesn't the generic specialization trait apply to std::array

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I find it interesting that this type trait doesn't match std::array(it gives a compilation error) but it works for unordered_map. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <array>

template <typename T, template <typename...> class Ref>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {
};

template <template <typename...> class Ref, typename... Args>
struct is_specialization<Ref<Args...>, Ref> : std::true_type {
};

int main()
{
    using T = std::unordered_map<int, int>;
    using C = std::array<int, 2>;
    auto value = is_specialization<T, std::unordered_map>::value;
    std::cout << "Is type of unorderd map specialization? : " << std::boolalpha << value << std::endl;

    auto secondValue = is_specialization<C , std::array>::value;
    std::cout << "Is type of array specialization? : " << std::boolalpha << secondValue << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the title then be "Why doesn't the generic specialization trait apply to std::array"? your code neither compiles using clang or gcc: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rJSo7XZasBff2MEs

Comment: @m.s yes, thank you, i changed the title. It doesn't compile because it can't match std::array to the trait, i don't understand why

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your primary template takes two arguments: a type argument and a template template parameter, whose template arguments are all **types**:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Ref>
struct is_specialization;
```

[`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a class template, yes, but its template arguments are not all types:

```
template< 
    class T, 
    std::size_t N  // <== not a type
> struct array;
```

Anything that isn't a type is a second-class citizen in the land of template metaprogramming. This is just one example of why values suck.

If you wrote your own `array` wrapper that did take two types:

```
template <typename T, typename N>
struct my_array : std::array<T, N::value> { };
```

then you could use your trait as you would expect:

```
using C = my_array<int, std::integral_constant<int, 2>>;
auto secondValue = is_specialization<C , my_array>::value; // true
```

Comment: `my_array` eliminates one of `std::array`'s more important features: it isn't an aggregate.